# ListView drag up the list view

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview as the main view in a fragment. I also have 2 `FloatingActionButton`s used for editing, one at the left and the other on the right. Sometimes, the `FloatingActionButton` hide part of the last view of the listview. I want the user to be able to "drag up" the listview to make the last view more visible. When the user releases it, it should go back to its position.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I don't think any code is necessary as it is a normal listview. I only want it to be able to "drag up" if the user scrolls below the last item. As it is now, if you try to scroll below the last item, the list view doesn't "stretch" up.

Comment: What if you just included empty rows at the bottom?

Comment: For different devices, the `FloatingActionButton`s obscure different positions of the last item. And i don't think it is the "right" way of doing it. The behavior i want is similar to the way you refresh some applications by dragging the listview and releasing it(i think GMail is like that). And to add empty rows, i would need to edit the `cursor` as the data is being populated from a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listview has an option for this called

```
listView.setOverscrollFooter()
```

You just pick a drawable into it like loading etc. or just a blank drawable would do your work.